# How much logical it seems when it's stated that in Mahabharata, queen Gandhari had 100 sons?

Tags: mahabharata, gandhari

I would like to know, is it in some way possible that a couple can have 100 sons ? I am trying to focus more on it's scientific reason. If a marriage of a girl occurs say at 10 years of age, and let's say after every 9 months, she delivers a baby. Then it should take approx 900 months to give birth to 100 babies. That is around 75 years. Which is about 10+75 = 85 .  So, what actually happened?

Comment: Weren't they all test tube babies (like artificially inseminated)?

Comment: ok, thanks. That link above provides the answer. I am ok with closing this question. Not sure, where to close it.